# python INT / date formatting

Tags: python, date, formatting

I am trying to use datetime module. I need the month to come back as a INT with the ZERO in front. in the form as 01 for JAN, 02 for FEB etc etc. I can get 1 by using,

```
 today = date.today()
 m = today.month
```

I can get the correct format but not as an INT this way.

```
 today.strftime("%m")
```

is there a simple way to get the desired format I need. I have looked in the reference and I am sure I am missing it, but could someone help.

Comment: works for me: `>>> import datetime; 
>>> a = datetime.datetime.now(); 
>>> print a.strftime('%m'); 
01`

Comment: I don't get your question. You want the month as INT, which can be `1,2,3...12`. But you ask it to be in the form `01, 02,03,...,12`, which is a string. Which one you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
'{:%m}'.format(datetime.datetime.now())
```

seems to work.

Of course, you could take the less direct approach:

```
'{:02d}'.format(datetime.datetime.now().month)
```

Or you could use old style string interpolation:

```
'%02d' % (datetime.datetime.now().month)
```

but I like the first one because I think it's cool ...

---

Finally, I don't see what is wrong with `.strftime` ... even though you said you tried it, it works just fine for me:

```
datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m')
```

---

What it seems like you're looking for is a special subclass of `int` which knows how to "represent" itself when it printed:

```
 class MyInt(int):
     def __str__(self):
         return '%02d' % self

 a = MyInt(3)
 print (a)
```

However, I would definitely not recommend using this approach, instead I would recommend using string formatting or string interpolation as I've done above on the integer objects when you need to represent the integers as strings.

Comment: @mgilson Very useful to mix and match as well - so one can even access an underlying attribute: `'{.month}'.format(now)` to get back a "1" instead of "01" (not required in this case, but sometimes useful)

Comment: @JonClements -- Yep.  Although, might I suggest `'{0.month}'.format(now)` instead?  It'll work with python2.6 whereas your version won't.  It's a very minor nitpick, but I prefer backwards compatability where it's easy to put in :), and I find that it is slightly more *explicit* where the data is coming from in the case where you pass more than 1 positional argument to `format`